# Changing text using Python

Tags: python, text, replace

I am attempting to replace text from a source file into a new file.
The replacing of text works for one line, but a few lines down and I fail to replace text sitting in the middle of a statement.

Here is the source text. The words in brackets are what I am trying to replace, without changing the characters around the words:

```
[set interfaces] ge-0/0/0 [description] "OoB Mgmt Connection"
```

This is what I would like to output:

`interface x/x name "xxx"` (also adding quotations for the xxx text after "name")

However the output text replaces once, and then keeps three copies of the original text:

```
    hostname "EX4300"
    set system host-name EX4300
    set system host-name EX4300
    set system auto-snapshot
    set system auto-snapshot
    set system auto-snapshot
```

Here is my code:

```
    with open("SanitizedFinal_E4300.txt", "rt") as fin:
         with open("output6.txt", "wt") as fout:
              for line in fin:
                  fout.write(line.replace('set system host-name EX4300', 'hostname "EX4300"'))
                  fout.write(line.replace('set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address', 'ip address'))
```

Please let me know where I went wrong or if there is a better way of approaching this.
I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you're trying to do. Can you give a complete source text, and a complete desired output?

Comment: just like your previous version of this question, it is still unclear what you want to search and replace

Answer (score 1):

Only use 1 `fout.write()`, call the replace function al often as you want.

```
with open("SanitizedFinal_E4300.txt", "rt") as fin:
    with open("output6.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            line = line.replace('set system host-name EX4300', 'hostname "EX4300"')
            line = line.replace('set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address', 'ip address')
            fout.write(line)
```